# Business logic in constructor - C# / Linq to Sql

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-3.5, class-design

I'm extending (not sure if it's the right word here) a partial Cart class that was generated in the Linq to SQL database model.

The business logic is that there can be only one Cart per customer. If a customer doesn't have a cart, it should be created; if a customer has a cart, it should be returned.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
public partial class Cart
{
    //the rest of the Cart class is in the .dbml file created by L2S
    public Cart(int userId)
    {
        Cart c = GetCurrentCart(userId);
        this.CartId = c.CartId ;
        this.UserId = c.UserId;
    }

    public Cart GetCurrentCart(int userId)
    {
        Cart currentCart = new Cart();

        // if cart exists - get it from DB
        //if not - create it, save in DB, and get if right out
        //all of this is done with Linq to SQL

        return currentCart;
    }
}
```

Calling a method from the constructor just doesn't seem right.  Am I enforcing the business logic the right way?

Answer (score 8):

I'd question why the "Cart" class is so smart. In Domain Driven Design terms, it sounds like the User "owns" the Cart. So why not something like:

```
var user = // Load a user
var cart = user.Cart;
```

In this case your Cart getter could lazily load/initialize the cart.

Comment: good point. is there anything wrong with my code besides it not being written DDD way?

Comment: I think it's interesting that with the code you posted, you yourself were unsure about whether doing database lookups in the constructor is the right thing. While it's not the worst crime, it is a bit of a code smell. I think this is a case where your instincts were good.

Comment: By code smell, I mean, it's something you're probably want to avoid doing (as your instincts have suggested). So looking for an alternative design (one that is more technically clean, as well as that makes more sense for the problem domain) is a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

I agree with Paul Stovell, it sounds like user should own the cart.  But at any rate, by the time your constructor is called you already have a new instance of Cart.  C# doesn't let you alter the reference returned by the constructor, so rather than clients of the Cart class using the constructor they should be calling a static factory method (I don't have experience with Linq to SQL, so this may not work directly).

Your GetCurrentCart method is almost this; you just need to mark it static.  Additionally, you should make the Cart constructor just responsible for creating a new Cart and make it private so that clients are forced to use GetCurrentCart.  An implementation might look something like this:

```
public partial class Cart
{
        // Make a new cart
        private Cart(int userId, int cartId)
        {
            this.CartId = userId;
            this.UserId = cartId;
        }

        private static Dictionary<int, Cart> CurrentCarts = new Dictionary<int, Cart>();

        public static Cart GetCurrentCart(int userId)
        {
            // TODO: Use a proper caching mechanism that will at least
            //       remove old carts from the dictionary.
            Cart cart;
            if (CurrentCarts.TryGetValue(userId, out cart))
            {
                return cart;
            }

            cart = /* try get cart from DB */;
            if (cart == null)
            {
                // Make a new cart
                cart = new Cart(userId, GenerateCartId());
            }

            CurrentCarts[userId] = cart;

            return cart;
        }
}
```

Comment: why dictionary? user can only have ONE cart

Comment: Note that the key for the dictionary is the userId, hence there can only be one cart per user.  The dictionary allows GetCurrentCart to return the exact same instance of Cart that it returned for the previous call with the same userId.